# How to prove $(\tan a + \tan b) / (\tan ab) = (\tan ab) / (\tan a - \tan b)$?

Tags: trigonometry

How would I prove $\dfrac{\tan a + \tan b }{ \tan ab }=\dfrac{ \tan ab } {\tan a - \tan b}$?

I have no idea because I've exhausted all possibilities that I know of, I've tried multiplying by the conjugate, expressing tan as sin/cos, etc.

How would I prove this?

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think it is true as written? Have you tried putting actual values in?

Comment: How would putting in values help me determine if it's true? We weren't taught that in school.

Comment: It would show if it is *not* true. In the real world, if you are given a function like that, and want to check equivalence, first try plugging in values and seeing if it works.

Comment: Let $a=b$. We get something that cannot be right.

Comment: My worksheet assumes all the trig identities are true and I'm just given the task of verifying that.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I am guessing that the algebra worksheet is not accounting for the obvious "hole"s in the range.

Comment: My question was "what makes you think it is true?". If you can't prove a statement it is worth doing a reality check. No scale is given for the angles (degrees, radians?), but whatever they are put $a=1$ and see what happens.

Comment: This is not a standard trig identity.

Comment: Are you looking for something like $\tan(a+b)=\frac {\tan a+\tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b}$?

Comment: No, we have not learned that one yet. I do have an identity that is similar to this question's though, this one is troubling me as well: (tan theta sin theta) / (tan theta + sin theta) = (tan theta - sin theta) / (tan theta sin theta)

Comment: Can you find values of $a$ and $b$ for which the suggested identity holds?

Comment: Well I did as Andre Nicolas said, which is to set a = b, and that automatically makes it a false identity so I'll leave it at that. I can't think of anything that holds.

Comment: If the identity is true, one can prove that $\pi$ is rational! Take $a=b=\pi/4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us start from 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\tan \theta -\sin \theta }{\sin \theta \tan \theta } &=&\frac{\left(
\tan \theta -\sin \theta \right) }{\sin \theta \tan \theta }\frac{\left(
\tan \theta +\sin \theta \right) }{\left( \tan \theta +\sin \theta \right) }
\\
&=&\frac{\tan ^{2}\theta -\sin ^{2}\theta }{\sin \theta \tan \theta }\cdot 
\frac{1}{\left( \tan \theta +\sin \theta \right) } \\
&=&\left( \tan ^{2}\theta -\sin ^{2}\theta \right) \cdot \frac{1}{\sin
\theta \tan \theta \left( \tan \theta +\sin \theta \right) } \\
&=&\left( \frac{\sin ^{2}\theta }{\cos ^{2}\theta }-\sin ^{2}\theta \right)
\cdot \frac{1}{\sin \theta \tan \theta \left( \tan \theta +\sin \theta
\right) } \\
&=&\left( \sin ^{2}\theta \cdot \left( \frac{1}{\cos ^{2}\theta }\right)
-\sin ^{2}\theta \right) \cdot \frac{1}{\sin \theta \tan \theta \left( \tan
\theta +\sin \theta \right) } \\
&=&\left( \sin ^{2}\theta \cdot \left( \tan ^{2}\theta +1\right) -\sin
^{2}\theta \right) \cdot \frac{1}{\sin \theta \tan \theta \left( \tan \theta
+\sin \theta \right) } \\
&=&\sin ^{2}\theta \left( \tan ^{2}\theta +1-1\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\sin
\theta \tan \theta \left( \tan \theta +\sin \theta \right) } \\
&=&\sin ^{2}\theta \tan ^{2}\theta \cdot \frac{1}{\sin \theta \tan \theta
\left( \tan \theta +\sin \theta \right) } \\
&=&\frac{\sin \theta \tan \theta }{\tan \theta +\sin \theta }.
\end{eqnarray*}
As was to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try $a=\frac{\pi}{3},b =\frac{\pi}{6}$ your formula isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the second identity, let us start from
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tan ^{2}\theta  &=&\frac{\sin ^{2}\theta }{\cos ^{2}\theta }=\sin
^{2}\theta \cdot \left( \frac{1}{\cos ^{2}\theta }\right)  \\
&=&\sin ^{2}\theta \cdot \left( \tan ^{2}\theta +1\right) ,\ \ \ \ \text{
since }\frac{1}{\cos ^{2}\theta }=\tan ^{2}\theta +1 \\
&=&\tan ^{2}\theta \cdot \sin ^{2}\theta +\sin ^{2}\theta 
\end{eqnarray*}
then transpose $\sin ^{2}\theta $ to the LHS, one gets
\begin{equation*}
\tan ^{2}\theta -\sin ^{2}\theta =\tan ^{2}\theta \cdot \sin ^{2}\theta 
\end{equation*}
which is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
\left( \tan \theta -\sin \theta \right) \left( \tan \theta +\sin \theta
\right) =\tan ^{2}\theta \cdot \sin ^{2}\theta 
\end{equation*}
which is equivalent to your send identity
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\tan \theta \cdot \sin \theta }{\tan \theta +\sin \theta }\left.
=\right. \frac{\tan \theta -\sin \theta }{\tan \theta \cdot \sin \theta }
\end{equation*}
as long as denominators are not zero.

Comment: How come tan^2 theta - sin^2 theta is equal to tan^2theta * sin^2 theta? DId you divide both sides?

Comment: if you have x=y+z then you move z from the right hand side to the left hand side you will get x-z=y. I moved $sin^2(theta)$ from right to left

Comment: In trigonometric proofs aren't you not allowed to move things from the left to the right and vice versa?

Comment: In trigonometric proofs as well as in algebraic proofs, we are allowed to move things from left to right and from right to left. What we should take care is when we divide by something, it should be not zero. (It do not depend on the trigonometric nature of things)

Comment: Hmm, I was always taught in class that you are not allowed to move something from the left to the right and vice versa because we assume the equivalency of the statement as we do that, so in other words by moving something we assume the two sides are equal.

Comment: OK Now I understand you! So , I will re-write the same proof in essence but in the accepted way for you (and your class). Just in few minutes...